# How to validate if keyword matched is highlighed or not in Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, automation, ruby-on-rails-plugins, regression-testing

I am writing a testing script using Ruby and Rails. I have to validate whether proper keyword is highlighted or not. How do i do in rub. For eg. "confidential" is my keyword and want to validate whether it got highlighted or not.

Comment: Highlighted? What do you mean by that? I do not understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you highlight your keyword with `<em>`-tags and have a HighLighter class that does the highlighting:

```
assert_contains "<em>confidential</em>", HighLighter.highlight(text)
```